# Primefaces 4.0 tries to call wrong tabChange event handler (AccordionPanel inside TabView)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, tabs

I have a page that displays some tabs. Each tab contains an accordion.

Technically, I have a `p:tabView` component which contains four `p:tab`. Let's call them `p:tabView > p:tab`. And inside each `p:tab`, I have a `p:accordionPanel`. I will refer to these as `p:accordionPanel > p:tab`.

My problem is that when the user opens one of the `p:tabView > p:tab`, then opens one of the `p:accordionPanel > p:tab`, then clicks on another `p:tabView > p:tab`, then I don't know how I can close (or "collapse") the currently opened `p:accordionPanel > p:tab`.

I tried  to solve the problem using two `onChange` event handlers but I hit a `methodNotFound` exception that I don't understand. My JSF code is:

```xml
<p:tabView dynamic="true" cache="false">
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{controller.onTabViewTabChange}" update="@this" />
    <p:tab title="tab 1">
        <p:accordionPanel id="accordionPanelForTab1" dynamic="true" activeIndex="-"
                 value="#{controller.viewBeans}"
                 var="viewBean">
            <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{controller.onAccordionPanelTabChange}" update="@this" />
            <p:tab title="#{viewBean.name}">
                <h:outputText value="#{viewBean.name}" />
            </p:tab>
        </p:accordionPanel>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="tab 2">
        <p:accordionPanel id="accordionPanelForTab2" dynamic="true" activeIndex="-"
                 value="#{controller.viewBeans}"
                 var="viewBean">
            ...
        </p:accordionPanel>
    </p:tab>
    ...
</p:tabView>
```

In my controller, I have the following event handlers :

```java
public void onAccordionPanelTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
    logger.info("onAccordionPanelTabChange, tab={}", event.getTab());
}

public void onTabViewTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
    logger.info("onTabViewTabChange, tab={}", event.getTab());
}
```

When I click on the `p:accordionPanel > p:tab`, I see the expected debug message in the console ("onAccordionPanelTabChange, tab=....").

But when I click on the `p:tabView > p:tab`, I get the following exception :

```
 javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: org.my.Controller@2691ab6b.onAccordionPanelTabChange(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)
```

So Primefaces seems to be able to have only one listener for the `tabChange` event. The exception refers to `onAccordionPanelTabChange` and not `onTabViewTabChange`.

**Is there a solution to the original problem of automatically closing the currently opened accordion when the user clicks on the `p:tabView p:tab`?**

NOTE : it seems to be a bug in PrimeFaces : https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3876

Comment: Try to use TabMenu 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabMenu.jsf 
instead of TabView

Comment: Thanks for your answer but TabMenu is not what I need (it reloads the page).

Comment: @geceo- it is a bug. Try the handler with an argument of `AjaxBehaviorEvent` instead of the `TabChangeEvent`

Comment: Thanks for commenting. With `AjaxBehaviorEvent`, the exception disappears, but the wrong function is called (`onAccordionPanelTabChange`) when I click on `p:tabView > p:tab`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it was a PrimeFaces bug, fixed for PF >= 5 : https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3876